# Finding rows which have a non distinct combination of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database called transactions. This table currently has 542,046 records for a particular site, which is three more than there should be. An issue occurred on uploading which meant the primary key in place wasn't sufficient.

I am going to be adding a new key, based on till and start_time to account for this in future data uploads.

However, as opposed to dropping and re-uploading all of the current data, I'm trying to find the 3 duplicate transactions and remove them.

When I run this query, I get 542,043 rows:

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct start_time, till_id FROM 
    schema.transactions where site_id = "siteNo"
  )table2
```

What I want, is the three transaction_ids that appear in the 542,046 rows, but not in the 542,043 rows.

Unfortunately the transaction ids are not the same for these duplicated rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select start_time, till_id,count(till_id) FROM 
    schema.transactions where site_id = "siteNo"
group by start_time, till_id
having count(till_id)>1
```